# Is there a VBA macro in excel that can enable copying and pasting in a " macro enabled excel worksheet "?

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I have an Excel Macro enabled Worksheet that contains a pivot table. I made a small macro in VBA to automatically refresh the pivot tables here is it:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
PivotTables("data").RefreshTable
End Sub
```

Now the problem I am facing is that when I try to do a normal drag fill or copy and paste it doesn't work normally. However, for the drag and fill I found a VBA code that solved the problem which is this:

```
Application.CellDragAndDrop = True
```

i tried the same syntax with the copy and paste using

```
Application.CutCopyMode = True
```

But it didn't work I can only copy but can't paste-like the cell get highlighted but when I click anywhere else to paste it's gone so is there anything I can do to fix it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really need to refresh the PT every time you select a cell??

Comment: no not to that extreme i only wanted it to refresh on entering any new value in the main table data source so the PT can update the values but that's not my problem tho. My problem is in the copying and pasting, do u think that this macro is responsible for my problem ?

Comment: That code runs every time you select any cell on the sheet.

Comment: ahaaa now i get why the other functions wouldn't work and solveddd it , thank youu